# Accessing field in super to report error

Tags: java

I'm not great with java terminology so it will be easier for you to understand via example:
I instantiate a mymethods class from a

Main class:

```
public class Main()
{
    public boolean hasErrors = false;
    MyMethods m = new MyMethods(); //cannot use try/catch
    public static void main(String[] args){
        m.writeToFile("text");
    }
}
```

In the above class, i cannot (i tried) use a try catch to catch a manually thrown FileNotFoundException but apparently such methods cannot be used in that location (wrapping `MyMethods m...` in try/catch). I had tried to throw that error when my requisite file wasnt found

MyMethods:

```
public class MyMethods()
{
    public MyMethods(){
        if(!new File("file.txt").canWrite()){
            changeSuper(true);
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }
    public void changeSuper(boolean b) //does not work
    {
        super.hasErrors = b;
    }
    //input more methods etc here
}
```

1. Why is it not possible to use try/catch?
2. How can i report a filenotfound to the main method?

Note that this is from a GUI app in netbeans, but is not the focus here. Program will not compile if try/catch wraps that line

**(note to admins/mods: this question needs butchering, but I cannot express my question better myself)**

Comment: `public class MyMethods()` doesn't compile in Java...

Comment: You just have to throw the exception from the method which you call from main method. Use try/catch in main method if find to propagate this exception to the main method

Comment: @janos It wouldnt, due to void method within. Although I did forget a curly

Comment: @Downvoter excuse me for not being able to submit a clean question on a dirty problem. I cannot word something right if i havent heard of it before

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the throws keyword to your method, i.e:

```
public static void myMethod() throws FileNotFoundException{
    // Code goes here ...
    if( fileNotFound )
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.");
}
```

you can then catch the exception by surrounding your call to the method with a try/catch block:

```
try {
    // Do stuff...
    myMethod();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    // Handle error, if thrown...
}
```

Comment: This is what i tried, netbeans does not allow compilation, saying "illegal start of type"

Comment: instantiate your MyMethods from inside your Main method instead.

Comment: Is that possible in a netbeans GUI project? AFAIK if the instantiation is anywhere else, all methods that call `m.method()` will not allow compilation since its in main method. Note that there are many methods in Main class that are on same level as `void main()`

Comment: You can still define it where it is now, you just don't assign anything to it until you start your program. I.e. remove the '=' onward (obviously leave the semicolon) and in your main method add in: m = new MyMethods();

public class Main()
{
    public boolean hasErrors = false;
    MyMethods m; //cannot use try/catch
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            m = new MyMethods(); 
            m.writeToFile("text");
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            // Stuff.....
        }
    }
}

Comment: "non static variable cannot be referenced from static context"

Comment: Since m belongs to the class (or at least it should...) you can set it to static. You're also missing an access modifier for that object. Either way it sounds like you need to go back to basics and do a little reading...

Comment: Converting the method in question in my program messes up the whole thing. Nullpointers everywhere
Note that the code submitted here is nothing but an example, my real code is better by far

Comment: Then you need to rethink and refactor. Of course, you could just move the implementation out of the constructor and add it into a separate method.

Comment: This question provides no insight to future readers, and although i appreciate the help, i would like to delete this question, would that be breaking any rules?